# Folder permissions. Allowed to read but not allowed to execute

Tags: permissions, windows-10

Dealing with a folder in windows 10, I am changing its permissions. When I go to security tab of its properties, I can see that I can allow or disallow:

- Full control
- Modify
- **Read and Execute**
- List folder contents
- Read
- Write

(The names might be different, my system is not in english). 
My question is, is there a way to set the permissions of this folder as in "alllowed to read, not allowed to execute"??
(above both are in one item together)

Answer (score 0):

**Read** and **Read and Execute** are two different permission "sets". If you want the user or group to only have the **Read** permissions then grant them only the **Read** permission and not the **Read and Execute** permission.

http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-file-folder.htm

Comment: Is the "list folder contents" the execute(traverse) permission?? (I am not native english speaker so don't get what traverse exactly implies)